# Authorize Attribute with Roles in ASP.NET Web API not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, thinktecture

I have ASP.NET MVC4 application project. I also added WebApi to my project by creating `ApiContoller`. I have Forms Authentication for MVC and Basic Authentication (Thinktecture) for Web API.

I noticed that in ApiContoller `[Authorize]` is working well but `[Authorize(Roles="")]` never let to invoke methods. I think the reason is that in MVC `Contoller` descendants both statements `User.IsInRole("");` and `Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "");` returns `true`, but in `ApiContoller` descendants first statement is always  `false`, when second returns `true` if user has role:

```
bool booool1 = User.IsInRole("Radiolog");
bool booool2 = Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Radiolog");
```

Here is my web.config configuration:

```
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    ...
        <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="RisSystem.Services.CustomRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        ...
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
```

In `ApiController` methods I am authenticating with: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(login, password);` (Thinktecture) and `FormsAuthentication` in MVC `Contoller`.

Authentication for WebApi is set in `WebApiConfig.cs` in `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` function:

```
        var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
        authConfig.AddBasicAuthentication((userName, password) => AuthenticationService.ValidateUser(userName, password));
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));
```

**Q: How to get to work Authorize Attribute with Roles in ASP.NET Web API**

Comment: The problem is that under your MVC request, the `User` is of type `RolePrincipal` and the `IsInRole` is evaluated correctly using your role manager. However, your WebAPI seems to use some other authentication module and the `User` is of some other type (`ClaimsPrincipal`? `WindowsPrincipal`?). What you show ("I am authenticating") looks like client authentication, you don't show what happens on the server. First, check what's the type of `User` under your WebAPI request and come back with more details.

Comment: `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` is the `User` type. 
Moreover I think the solution for my problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25587270/3243859, but in my Thniktecture library there is no `AddBasicAuthorization()` overload taking delegate for user's roles :(

Comment: Yes, this would be the solution. The `ClaimsPrincipal` supports roles, too, but assuming roles are somehow provided there.

Comment: The API seems to be there: https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/cda89ad369d19c87f5f3414246be57c450332756/source/WebApi.AuthNHandler/AuthenticationConfigurationExtensionsCore.cs

Comment: I don't know why, I don't have those extension methods in file installed with nuGet...

Comment: Have you added `using ...` the namespace where the extension is defined?

Comment: There's no Thinktecture.IdentityModel.WebApi.Authentication.Handler
namespace in the library...

Comment: It is there, you just miss a proper nuget package. Try this one: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.WebApi.AuthenticationHandler/

Comment: The screenshot taken from my VS a minute ago: http://s28.postimg.org/tpr1l7app/thinktecture.png

Comment: Reason is .net-4.0 in my project...

Comment: That means you have your answer.